# Can sorting Algorithms destroy pre-existing element order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was wondering about an Issue I have.

My Situations looks as following:

I have a set of Data and 2 comparators.
You can assume the first comparator sorts items alphabetically and the other one sorts items based on some other Criteria (f.e. custom level value).

So given following data:

```
1: b / lvl 1
2: c / lvl 1
3: a / lvl 1
4: d / lvl 2
```

after first sort it should look like this:

```
a, b, c, d
```

and after the second one:

```
d, a, b, c
```

So far so good.
I know that it is possible to destroy the first sorting (f.e. by using Bogosort).
So that could be the output of the second sort:

```
d, b, c, a
```

But are there any "proper" sorting algorithms which could do that too?

Comment: not clear what you are asking about but it seems related to stable sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is [stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability):

> When sorting some kinds of data, only part of the data is examined when determining the sort order. For example, in the card sorting example to the right, the cards are being sorted by their rank, and their suit is being ignored. The result is that it's possible to have multiple different correctly sorted versions of the original list. Stable sorting algorithms choose one of these, according to the following rule: if two items compare as equal, like the two 5 cards, then their relative order will be preserved, so that if one came before the other in the input, it will also come before the other in the output.

Many algorithms are stable and many others aren't.

Two fairly well-known examples - (typical) [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is unstable, and [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is stable.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) for a long list of sorting algorithms, including whether or not they're stable.

Comment: Thx, I pretty much failed googling it. Didn't knew what to search for. :)